# Is it really neccesary to throw us to captchas more than once while asking a question?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, captcha

When I [last asked a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15289/meta-faq-should-be-updated-to-reflect-recent-league-of-justice-additions), I was thrown to a captcha page 3 times in the process of trying to figure out [which tag was for moderator use only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15299/be-specific-about-which-tags-are-restricted-for-moderator-use). This was really, *really* annoying.

After proving that I'm not a robot once in editing a question, why should I need to do so any more times?

Comment: Request #40420329

Comment: I think I saw at least 12 dups or related questions about this after searching.

Comment: You're not a **robot,** *are you?!
Surely only a **robot** would be so afraid of dull, repetitive tasks...

Comment: There are a lot of captcha questions, but my point is that I shouldn't be asked more than once while in the process of asking a question.

Comment: I updated the title to make this more clear

Comment: Robots can edit questions too. Think of their feelings.

Comment: I think the issue is with the rather poor system that serves as the logic of captcha system. From my own tests it seems it uses a single time based indicator to make decisions. Changing any captcha behaviour would require a massive overhaul.

Comment: Have you ever harmed a human being or through inaction, allowed a human being to come to harm?

Answer (score 6):

But what if between request #1 and #2, you were turned *INTO* a robot?

Comment: Jared brings up a good point. It's an affliction affecting dozens. Let's stop spontaneous robotification. Together, we can make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Howabout instead of showing a captcha just after "Post Your Answer" is clicked  under suspicious circumstances, the captcha page is only shown at the very end of the journey. That is, once the question/answer/whatever is *completely* verified, the user is given a captcha if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are a logged in user and have >= 200 reputation:

After successfully completing one captcha, we now suppress captcha for 5 minutes on your account.