# Captcha bug/feature when making mistakes on submission?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, asking-questions, captcha

I've just attempted to submit a question to `meta` and forgot to put any tags on it. I added a single tag and re-submitted and was told that I needed to add one of a specific set of tags. I added this and re-submitted and was taken to captcha.

Is this by-design? I wonder if any newbie users have been put off answering questions due to a *3-strikes-and-you're-out* reaction? i.e. "this site has just prevented me from posting 3 times, I can't be bothered with it."

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15303/you-want-how-many-robots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've just attempted to submit a question to meta and forgot to put any tags on it.

Unless you have JavaScript disabled, this should be blocked by the client before it gets to the server based on length = 0.

Can't repro that.

The meta-blocking of tags is highly specific to meta, and something of a beta feature at the moment, so everything else is by-design.

Comment: I was able to click the button "Ask Question" which promptly greyed out and then I saw the red test "Tags required" (or something like that). I've just checked this behaviour again and it's certainly the case, although I believe you when you say this is client-side JS. I'm not sure why I got the captcha request then: odd

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the requirement for one of the meta-specific tags should be in the [meta faq](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq)?

Having said that, though, I expect most users learn the need for one of these tags through the same process you went through. The captcha doesn't stop you submitting the question, it just delays it briefly or (in the worst case) you just start again. Presumably the learning process worked as you've also submitted this question successfully?